# Compiled .Jade to .JS...How To Use As Backbone Template in Require.JS?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, pug

So I compiled .Jade to .js.
How would I use a .js template in backbone.js with require.js?
Ive tried something like this:

```
define(['marionette'], 
function(Marionette) {

return CoreNorthLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: require('/to/folder/templatename')
});

});
```

But no work, anything else I can try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade is going to generate just a single javascript function source code: `function anonymous(locals){...}`. You need to wrap this with an AMD wrapper to use it with requirejs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I found that Grunt-Contrib-Jade can be used to compile it with an AMD wrapper